# PowerShell split input and replace/combine?

Tags: powershell, split

I want to be able to automatically generate an output if I run a PowerShell script that splits the input by a period "." and adds "DC=" in each item/object that has been split.

```
$DomainFQDN = "prod.mydomain.com"   # This varies depending on the input. It could be "prod.boston.us.mydomain.com" as the input.
$DistinguishedName = $DomainFQDN -split "\."
...
...
...I just don't know how to proceed
```

How do I get an output of "DC=prod,DC=mydomain,DC=com" for prod.mydomain.com as the input or ***DC=prod,DC=boston,DC=us,DC=mydomain,DC=com*** for prod.boston.us.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, this is what needed:

```
$fqdn='prod.boston.us.mydomain.com'
$dn="DC=$($fqdn.replace('.',',DC='))"
$dn
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use foreach construct with $DistinguishedName and use -join like this (if you want to output directly the joined string):

```
$AddDC = foreach ($e in $DistinguishedName) { "DC=$e" }
Write-Host $($AddDC -join ",")
```

-join works like -split, you just specify the character that you need to join by.
Other way to do it is to store $AddDC

```
$AddDC = foreach ($e in $DistinguishedName) { "DC=$e" }
$new_string = $AddDC -join ","
Write-Host $new_string
```

You can consult this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
$DomainFQDN = "prod.mydomain.com"

$DomainFQDN = $DomainFQDN.Split(".")
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $DomainFQDN.Count; $i++) {
    $DomainFQDN[$i] = "DC=" + $DomainFQDN[$i]
}

$DomainFQDN = $DomainFQDN -join ","
Write-Host $DomainFQDN
```

Output:

```
DC=prod,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

I'm not sure why I couldn't get the -Split "." operator to work.  It should function the same as .Split(".") but for some reason it gives a different result.  But anyway this should work for you.

I feel like I should mention that a real FQDN would not be DC= on every line.  It would look more like:

```
DC=Com,DC=MyDomain,OU=Prod
```

Comment: The split operator uses regular expressions by default so the . was being interpreted as a regex special character.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do a single replace operation in an expandable to convert from FQDN to distinguished name of the domain root:

```
$DistinguishedName = "DC=$($DomainFQDN.TrimEnd('.') -replace '\.',',DC=')"
```

The `TrimEnd('.')` call strips any dot from rooted FQDNs, and the replace operation replaces each remaining dot with `,DC=`